# Cannot get gomobile binding to work with java

Tags: java, android, go, react-native, gomobile

**Go version**: 1.7.5

**GOPATH** = *D:/GoWork*

**React Native** version 0.41

Code below is the binding go package at ***D:\GoWork\src\rngo\rngo\rngo.go***

Very simple, just returning a string

```
package rngo

// RNcall is used to bind with RN
func RNcall()  string {
    return "From Go platform"
}
```

Running the below command from > ***D:\GoWork\src\rngo***

```
gomobile bind -target android -o rngo.aar -v  .
```

*Verbose Output below seems to be fine*

> write C:\Users\Minty\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-855641675\gomobile_bind\classes.go
>
> write C:\Users\Minty\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-855641675\gomobile_bind\classes.h
>
> write C:\Users\Minty\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-855641675\gomobile_bind\classes.c
>
> write C:\Users\Minty\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-855641675\gen\src\Java\interfaces.go
> rngo/rngo
>
> write C:\Users\Minty\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-855641675\fakegopath\pkg\android_arm\rngo\rngo.a
> write C:\Users\Minty\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-855641675\gomobile_bind\go_rngomain.go
>
> write C:\Users\Minty\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-855641675\gomobile_bind\go_main.go
>
> write C:\Users\Minty\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-855641675\androidlib\main.go
>
> write C:\Users\Minty\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-855641675\android\src\main\java\rngo\Rngo.java
>
> write C:\Users\Minty\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-855641675\gomobile_bind\java_rngo.c
>
> write C:\Users\Minty\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-855641675\gomobile_bind\rngo.h
>
> write C:\Users\Minty\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-855641675\android\src\main\java\go\Universe.java
>
> write C:\Users\Minty\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-855641675\android\src\main\java\go\error.java
>
> write C:\Users\Minty\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-855641675\gomobile_bind\java_universe.c
>
> write C:\Users\Minty\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-855641675\gomobile_bind\universe.h
>
> write C:\Users\Minty\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-855641675\gomobile_bind\seq_android.go
>
> write C:\Users\Minty\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-855641675\gomobile_bind\seq_android.c
>
> write C:\Users\Minty\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-855641675\gomobile_bind\seq.h
>
> write C:\Users\Minty\AppData\Local\Temp\gomobile-work-855641675\gomobile_bind\seq.go
>
> Java
> */C*/Users/Minty/AppData/Local/Temp/gomobile-work-855641675/gomobile_bind command-line-arguments rngo/rngo Java
>
> */C*/Users/Minty/AppData/Local/Temp/gomobile-work-855641675/gomobile_bind command-line-arguments rngo/rngo Java
>
> */C*/Users/Minty/AppData/Local/Temp/gomobile-work-855641675/gomobile_bind command-line-arguments rngo/rngo Java
>
> */C*/Users/Minty/AppData/Local/Temp/gomobile-work-855641675/gomobile_bind
>
> /# */C*/Users/Minty/AppData/Local/Temp/gomobile-work-855641675/gomobile_bind
>
> D:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\x86_64-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin\ld:
> warning: skipping incompatible
> D:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\platforms\android-21\arch-x86_64/usr/lib/liblog.so
> while searching for log
>
> D:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\x86_64-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin\ld:
> warning: skipping incompatible
> D:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\platforms\android-21\arch-x86_64/usr/lib/libdl.so
> while searching for dl
>
> D:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\x86_64-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin\ld:
> warning: skipping incompatible
> D:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\platforms\android-21\arch-x86_64/usr/lib/libc.so
> while searching for c
>
> D:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\x86_64-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin\ld:
> warning: skipping incompatible
> D:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\platforms\android-21\arch-x86_64/usr/lib/libdl.so
> while searching for dl
>
> command-line-arguments
>
> aar: AndroidManifest.xml
>
> aar: proguard.txt
>
> aar: classes.jar
>
> jar: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
>
> jar: go/LoadJNI.class
>
> jar: go/Seq$GoObject.class
>
> jar: go/Seq$Proxy.class
>
> jar: go/Seq$Ref.class
>
> jar: go/Seq$RefMap.class
>
> jar: go/Seq$RefTracker.class
>
> jar: go/Seq.class jar: go/Universe$proxyerror.class jar:
> go/Universe.class
>
> jar: go/error.class
>
> jar: rngo/Rngo.class
>
> aar: jni/armeabi-v7a/libgojni.so
>
> aar: jni/arm64-v8a/libgojni.so
>
> aar: jni/x86/libgojni.so
>
> aar: jni/x86_64/libgojni.so
>
> aar: R.txt
>
> aar: res/

**Successfully created** rngo.aar since there is no error message and I can see that file at ***D:\GoWork\src\rngo\rngo.aar***

I then manually import rngo.aar file into React Native project from android studio

1. **File > New > New Module > Import .aar/.jar Package > #give the path
   to rngo.aar#**
2. **File > Project Structure > app > Dependencies >
    Module dependency > rngo.aar**

Inside IDE, in MainActivity.java I can successfully do **'import go.rngo.*;'**, but I cannot get **'go.rngo.Rngo.RNcall()'** or **'go.rngo.Rngo;'** to work

[image]

Building this android app throws error **'cannot find symbol'**

> ***D:\RN\gomobile\android\app\src\main\java\com\gomobile\RngoModule.java:10***:
> error: cannot find symbol
>
> import go.rngo;
> ^
>
> symbol:   class rngo
> location: package go
> 1 error
> :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

[image]

**Conclusion**

I am doing something horribly wrong, that I cannot get this simple thing to work. I wasted whole day on google but with no avail. Hence I need help getting this to work. All I need is a simple go code with that connects to react native hasselfree.

***Thanks for reading all this. I appreciate it.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [eliasnaur](https://github.com/eliasnaur). Finally, I got this working. As of go 1.7.* you dont have access to go package. Instead access your package directly like this

Before:

```
import go.rngo.Rngo;
```

After:(Since 1.7.*)

```
import rngo.Rngo;
```